# Why are these MySQL errors coming up?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php
    require_once 'init.php';

    $selectpost = mysql_query("
        SELECT 
         posts.id, 
         posts.author, 
         posts.postText

        FROM posts

        GROUP BY posts.id

   ");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($selectpost)) { //line 30

        $posts[] = $row;    
    }
?>

<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?> //line 37

    <div class="post row">
     <p><?php echo $post->author; ?> said: </p>
     <p><?php echo $post->postText; ?></p>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I am trying to display some posts from a database. This is my code I have written so far. For some reason I am getting these errors:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in posts.php on line 30
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: posts in posts.php on line 37
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in posts.php on line 37

I have commented on the appropriate lines.

Comment: mixing mysql and mysqli hmmm ????

Comment: @Vicky which would be better to use?

Comment: now mysqli is a better option

Comment: use mysqli or pdo, mysql_* functions are deprecated

Comment: Use `mysqli` or `PDO` with prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing `mysql` & `mysqli`.It should be `mysqli_query` instead of `mysql_query` if you are using `mysqli`. You are missing the `connection object` -

```
$selectpost = mysqli_query($conn, "
        SELECT 
         posts.id, 
         posts.author, 
         posts.postText
        FROM posts
        GROUP BY posts.id
   ");
```

[mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php)

Comment: $conn = new mysqli("host","root","pass","mydb");

is it fine to connect just like this in mysqli?

Answer (score 0):

I changed and tested working fine, check once. In your code not connects db so records not comming..

```
 <?php
    //require_once 'init.php';
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db=mysql_select_db("test",$con);
    $selectpost = mysql_query("
    SELECT 
     posts.id, 
     posts.author, 
     posts.postText
     FROM posts
     GROUP BY posts.id
     ");
     while($row = mysql_fetch_object($selectpost)) { //line 30
     $posts[] = $row;    
    }
 ?>

<?php print_r($row);  foreach($posts as $post): ?> 

<div class="post row">
 <p><?php echo $post->author; ?>  </p>
 <p><?php echo $post->postText; ?></p>
</div>
```